# Progress bar for sklearn model that does NOT have a "verbose" parameter

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, progress-bar

When I'm training a machine learning model I like to know an estimate of how long it will take to finish running. If I'm using the sci-kit learn library, and presuming that I do not have a loop where I can use something like tqdm, is there a way to gauge the progress of my model?

I know some sci-kit learn models have a "verbose" parameter but there are many that do not, such as [AdaBoostClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html), [LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) and [OneVsRestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html).

What would you recommend using in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how a progressbar should work. E.g. LinearRegression can be implemented as an Ordinary Least Squares Proplem which is the computation of Pseudo Inverse.
For [AdaBoostPaper](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/samme.pdf) you loop once about each each estimator so maybe you can estimate your training duration by timing the fit of few estimators and then scale it up?